# Как определить кодировку строки и преобразовать в utf8?

Tags: python, кодировка, imap

Через `imap` подключаюсь к серверу и получаю список сообщений. Проблема в кодировке тела письма - в `гугле` оно одно, в `яндексе` другое. Хочу чтобы система автоматом определяла кодировку и преобразовывала его в `utf8`

```
import cchardet
def convert_encoding(data, new_coding = 'UTF-8'):
    encoding = cchardet.detect(data)['encoding']
    if new_coding.upper() != encoding.upper():
        data = data.decode(encoding, data).encode(new_coding)
    return data

def get_mails(login, password):
    print("Connecting to {}...".format(server))
    imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(server)
    print("Connected! Logging in as {}...".format(login));
    imap.login(login, password)
    print("Logged in! Listing messages...");
    status, select_data = imap.select('INBOX')
    nmessages = select_data[0].decode('utf-8')
    status, search_data = imap.search(None, 'ALL')
    for msg_id in search_data[0].split(): 
        status, msg_data = imap.fetch(msg_id, '(RFC822)')
        msg_raw = msg_data[0][1].decode("utf8")

        mail = mailparser.parse_from_string(msg_raw)
        telo = convert_encoding(mail.body.encode()) # Вот тут траблы
```

Для примера - `mail.body` содержит следующий текст

```
'<div>\\u041f\\u0440\\u043e\\u0432\\u0435\\u0440\\u043a\\u0430 \\u0441</div>'
```

Выдаёт ошибку

```
TypeError: decode() argument 2 must be str, not bytes
```

Comment: Ошибка - вполне логична, ведь decode применяется к байтовой строке. А у вас декодируется уже декодированная...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуй использовать [chardet](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) для определения кодировки. Эта библиотека может определить вероятность использования кодировки в тексте.

```
import chardet

rawdata = b"Тело сообщения"    
meta = chardet.detect(rawdata)
try:
    rawdata.decode(meta['encoding'])
except: KeyError:
    print('Кодировка не известна')
```

Для извлечения символов из кода html, следует воспользоватся `html.unscape`

```
import html
print(html.unescape('&pound;682m'))
```

Comment: `select_data[0].decode('utf-8')` chardet следует использовать здесь и при `msg_data[0][1].decode("utf8")`

Answer (score 2):

`data = data.decode(encoding, str(data)).encode(new_coding)`
Попробуй преобразовать в строку c помощью `str()`.